# Openedge add text at the beginning of an existing text file

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Found some kb on append text at the end of an xml file

https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P8379

```
OUTPUT TO VALUE ("cust.xml") APPEND.
/* Append a new line character to the end of the file */
PUT UNFORMATTED "~n ".
/* Append some text after the new line character */
PUT UNFORMATTED "this is the appended text".
OUTPUT CLOSE.
```

is there similar solution to add text at the beginning? or I have to resort to import the file and rewriting it to a new file?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to have to read it and re-write it. This is one way to do it:

```
define variable fileBody as longchar no-undo.

copy-lob from file "test" to fileBody.

fileBody = "new first line~n" + fileBody.

copy-lob from fileBody to file "test".
```